# Why is the which command so hard to eradicate?

Tags: shell, posix, history, portability, which

I'm coming from places like [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script and am myself a long-time proponent of advising against the use of `which` for all the well-known reasons. But this is looking like an uphill battle.

Why is it so hard to get people to abandon the `which` command?

Many other POSIX innovations which were originally met with opposition and skepticism have over time become part of the normal U*x canon, but this seems to be one where adoption in the field is extremely spotty.

I'd like to understand why this specific POSIX recommendation is so hard for people to take to heart. Is it just that the POSIX stance has not been stable (first [`type`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html), now [`command`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html))? Or is it because the POSIX name `command` is somehow hard to remember or internalize? (I am wondering if Bash had `command` before POSIX did, perhaps with slightly different semantics?) Or is it still just the inundating mass of all the sites and forum posts which still recommend `which`, along with its undoubtedly slightly catchy name?

Comment: Maybe you should give people a reason to abandon the `which` command -- eg. make them believe that using `which` costs them 350M a week.

Answer (score 1):

Because `command -v` is not a direct replacement for `which`;

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/1162

`which`

- outputs full path,
- ignores shell built-ins and functions,
- returns true only if all exist
- outputs bin instead of alias
- is available in dash unlike `type -p`
- the overwhelming majority of computers use ~5 flaviours of Bash/Linux, so incompatible implementations are rare.

Comment: It's not like `which` would *reliably* provide any or all of these, either. Part of the rationale for replacing it with a different command was that there were many incompatible implementations, which is still true to this day. But thanks for the link!

Comment: See the comment I added to the bug report just now: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/1162#issuecomment-517907020 (which redirects to the question I link in my question) but more fundamentally, I am not saying specifically that you should use `command -v` in every instance where you would otherwise use `which`

Comment: In  reaction to the latest edit: "Not caring about portability", while probably part of the true answer, is particularly non sequitur. Anyway, Bash does not have `which`, though the system where it is running might have one of the `which` commands installed. (But which one?)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @user1133275's answer and related comments, one cannot always tell whether `which` or `type` is being used.  Personally, my fingers are just trained to use `which` and I find that command name more mnemonically intuitive.  But in fact, I am actually using `type`:

```
$ which which
$ which type
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
$ type which
which is a function
which () 
{ 
    type -path ${1+"$@"}
}
```

If tomorrow, someone comes up with a better command, I'll change my `.profile` and continue using my customized `which`.

In short, I think it's hard to eradicate because the name correlates well with its function.

Comment: Okay for habits which are hard to break. What aliases or functions you have defined for interactive use is something I would discount as private convenience. I have a lot of personal shorthands which however never leak into scripts I write or advice I share on the net:

Comment: @tripleee Fair point.  It's just hard to eradicate because it's a catchy name.